# Рендер Jade - шаблона angular-ом

Tags: node.js, angularjs, jade, шаблоны

На *ноде* используется фреймворк *koa.js* (но это неважно, может быть любой). Шаблонизатор - *jade*.

Есть страница, к которой подключен *Angular* (все директивы инициализированны правильно), также в ней есть директива *ng-view*.

Эта страница рендерится *node*, когда заходим на *URL* `/some`, а в этот момент *Angular* имеет *роут* `/some`, который загружает вместо директивы *ng-view* кусочек другого шаблона.

Все чудесно работает, но беда в том, что этот кусочек шаблона, который *ангуляр* подключает, является  *jade*-файлом, и он не обрабатывается обработчиком, так как он вызывается не серверной *нодой*, а *ангуляром*, и в результате выводится как есть - строкой.

Т.е. в итоге получаем сплошную строку: `h1 Добро пожаловать div Часть 1`

Можно ли реализовать подобное?

Т.е. чтобы *ангуляр* загружал в *ng-view* шаблон *jade* и нормально его рендерил, а не просто строкой?

Или использовать обычный *html* (тогда все хорошо).

П.С. вариант чисто с *нодой* не подошел, потому что хочу подгружать кусочки шаблонов без перезагрузки, а *нода* перегружает страницу, к сожалению.

Answer (score 2):

Нельзя. Используйте bundler (grunt/gulp/webpack), чтобы jade транслировать в html и отдавать уже html.

Answer (score 0):

Напишите эту часть на HTML и вставьте в Jade-шаблон с помощью экранирования:

```
   div
      | <h1>Добро пожаловать</h1><div>Часть 1</div>
```